# Styleguidist grouping components in one page

Tags: reactjs, react-styleguidist

We have svg icons as components so the folder structure is kind of like

```
components
  / -- icons
     -- Readme.md
    /-- Check
        -- Check.tsx
        -- index.ts
    /-- Cross
        -- Cross.tsx
        -- index.ts
    /-- Cloud
        -- Cloud.tsx
        -- index.ts
```

Obviously we dont want a section per icon, we would like to have one single Section to show all the usages. So I created the section like this:

```
 sections: [
    {
      name: 'Cards',
      components: [
        // ... other components,
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Icons',
      components: [
        'components/icons/Check',
        'components/icons/Cross',
        'components/icons/Cloud',
      ],
      content: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'components', 'icon', 'readme.md')
    },
  ],
```

However the doc shows
`ReferenceError: Check is not defined`

if I add a `Readme.md` under each icon folder, it will work, but that's not what I would like.

any idea?